# how to remove zero packets (empty streams) records in wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I am very new to wireshark. in my day to day job i need to remove the packet bytes zero records from captured PCAP file. please help me in this process. attached image is for reference

[wireshark packets zero.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXEbR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 47 TCP Streams and 28 that you want to remove, it might be a bit faster to filter for all the TCP streams that you do want to keep since there are only 19 of those.

For the 19 streams you want:

- Right-click on the first TCP conversation and choose *"Prepare a Filter -> Selected -> A<-->B"*.
- For the next 17 TCP conversations, right-click on each one and choose *"Prepare a Filter -> ... And Selected -> A<-->B"*.
- Finally, for the last TCP stream, right-click on the TCP conversation and choose *"Apply as Filter -> ... And Selected -> A<-->B"*.

You may wish to export the resulting filtered packets to a new file via *"File -> Export Specified Packets... -> All packets:Displayed"* so you won't have to keep filtering for those streams anymore.

Comment: thanks Christopher for your response.  this is a big process. thats why i am looking if there is a filter criteria to apply in filter field like like to filter https we use "tcp.port == 443".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of streams to filter, then you are better off scripting something.  Here's a script you can use that seems to work well in my testing on my Linux machine.  If you're using Windows, you will need to write an equivalent batch file, or you may be able to use it as is if you have Cygwin installed.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check usage
if [ ${#} -lt 2 ] ; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <infile> <outfile>"
        exit 0
fi

infile=${1}
outfile=${2}

# TODO: Could also pass the filter on the command-line too.
filter="ip.dst eq 192.168.10.44 and tcp.len > 0"

stream_filter=
for stream in $(tshark -r ${infile} -Y "${filter}" -T fields -e tcp.stream | sort -u | tr -d '\r')
do
        if [[ -z ${stream_filter} ]] ; then
                stream_filter="tcp.stream eq ${stream}"
        else
                stream_filter+=" or tcp.stream eq ${stream}"
        fi
done

tshark -r ${infile} -Y "${stream_filter}" -w ${outfile}
echo "Wrote ${outfile}"
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I tried it and the first 4 lines was stoppoing the script. So, i removed them and most of the work has done for me. Thanks a lot. the filter is happening for both src and Dst of specified ip address even we mentioned as "ip.dst" in filter only this small issue is pending now to complete my task. please help me with this also.

Comment: I don't recommend this since doing so would mess up Wireshark analysis, but if you really only want 1-way communication, then you could modify the first `stream_filter="tcp.stream eq ${stream}" to  `stream_filter=ip.dst eq 192.168.10.44 and (tcp.stream eq ${stream}"` and then append `stream_filter+=")"` after the closing `fi` of the `if` statement.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I got an error when i applied the above mentioned stream filter. the error message is as follows here. line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./DestSpecific1.sh: line 7: `stream_filter="tcp.stream eq ${stream}" to stream_filter=ip.dst eq 192.168.10.44 and (tcp.stream eq ${stream}"` and then append stream_filter+=")"'
"

Comment: It looks like I inadvertently omitted a quote in my comment.  Try: `stream_filter="ip.dst eq 192.168.10.44 and (tcp.stream eq ${stream}"`.

Comment: ohhhh!! today my system started giving new issue as it doesnt find TSHARK command. i didnt do any changes in my system configuration. may be some system glitch it has broken the tshark identification to cygwin